# How to use locations.kml with sitemap.xml

Tags: kml, xml-sitemap

I would like to make sure website ranks as high as possible whenever my Google Places location ranks high.

I have seen references to creating a locations.kml file and putting it in the root directory of my site. Then creating lines in the sitemap.xml file to point to this .kml file.

I get this from this statement on the geolocations page
Google no longer supports the Geo extension to the Sitemap protocol. We recommmend that you tell Google about geographically-based URLs by including them in a regular Web Sitemap.

There is a link to the Web Sitemap page 
http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183668

I'm looking for examples of how to include Geo location information in the sitemap.xml file.

Would someone please point me to an example so that I can know how to code the reference?

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is that you dont use any specific formatting in the sitemap. You make sure you include all your locally relevent pages in the sitemap as normal. (ie you dont include any geo location in the sitemap)

GoogleBot will use its normal methods for detereriming if the page should be locally targeted.

(I think Google have found the sitemap-protocol has been abused, and or misunderstood, so they dont need it to tell them so much about the page. Rather its just a way to find pages, that it might take a long time to discover though conventual means. )